# Apollo/GraphQL: Setting Up Resolver for String Fields?

Tags: meteor, graphql, apollo-server

In GraphiQL at `http://localhost:8080/graphiql`, I'm using this query:

```
{
  instant_message(fromID: "1"){
    fromID
    toID
    msgText
  }
}
```

I'm getting this response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "instant_message": {
      "fromID": null,
      "toID": null,
      "msgText": null
    }
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Resolve function for \"instant_message.fromID\" returned undefined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "message": "Resolve function for \"instant_message.toID\" returned undefined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "message": "Resolve function for \"instant_message.msgText\" returned undefined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to set up my system according to the examples found here:

https://medium.com/apollo-stack/tutorial-building-a-graphql-server-cddaa023c035#.s7vjgjkb7

Looking at that article, it doesn't seem to be necessary to set up individual resolvers for string fields, but I must be missing something.

What is the correct way to update my resolvers so as to return results from string fields? Example code would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks very much in advance to all for any thoughts or info.

**CONNECTORS**

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

//SQL CONNECTORS
const db = new Sequelize(Meteor.settings.postgres.current_dev_system.dbname, Meteor.settings.postgres.current_dev_system.dbuser, Meteor.settings.postgres.current_dev_system.dbpsd, {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres',

});

db
    .authenticate()
    .then(function(err) {
        console.log('Connection to Sequelize has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the Sequelize database:', err);
    });

const IMModel = db.define('IM', {
    id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    fromID: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    toID: {type: Sequelize.STRING},
    msgText: {type: Sequelize.STRING}
});

IMModel.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
    // Table created
    return IMModel.create({
        fromID: '1',
        toID: '2',
        msgText: 'msg set up via IMModel.create'
    });
});

const IM = db.models.IM;
export {db, IM };
```

**SCHEMA**

```
const typeDefinitions = [`

type instant_message {
  id: Int
  fromID: String
  toID: String
  msgText: String
}
type Query {
  instant_message(fromID: String, toID: String, msgText: String): instant_message
}
type RootMutation {
  createInstant_message(
    fromID: String!
    toID: String!
    msgText: String!
  ): instant_message
}
schema {
  query: Query,
  mutation: RootMutation
}
`];

export default typeDefinitions;
```

**RESOLVERS**

```
import * as connectors from './db-connectors';
import { Kind } from 'graphql/language';
const b = 100;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        instant_message(_, args) {
            const a = 100;
            return connectors.IM.find({ where: args });
        }
    },
    RootMutation: {
        createInstant_message: (__, args) => { return connectors.IM.create(args); },
  },

};

export default resolvers;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define your `GraphQLObjectType`s you need to provide a resolver for each of their fields.

You defined your `instant_message` with multiple fields but did not provide resolvers for each of these fields.
More over you defined the types of those field with regular typescript fields while you need to define it with `GraphQL` types (`GraphQLInt, GraphQLString, GrapQLFloat` etc..)

So defining your type should look something like this:

```
let instant_message = new GraphQLObjectType({
  id: { 
    type: GraphQLInt,
    resolve: (instantMsg)=> {return instantMsg.id}
  }
  fromID: { 
    type: GraphQLString,
    resolve: (instantMsg)=> {return instantMsg.fromID}
  }
  toID: {
    type: GraphQLString,
    resolve: (instantMsg)=> {return instantMsg.toID}
  }
  msgText: { 
    type: GraphQLString,
    resolve: (instantMsg)=> {return instantMsg.msgText}
  }
})
```

In addition, you will need to define your Query as follows:

```
let Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "query",
    description: "...",

    fields: () => ({
        instant_messages: {
            type: new GraphQLList(instant_message),
            args: {
                id: {type: GraphQLInt}
            },
            resolve: (root, args) => {
                connectors.IM.find({ where: args })
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Apollo is a bit different from GraphQL. Is that Apollo syntax?

Comment: I tried the syntax out. It did not throw an error, but I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: I see. it might really be about the fact your Query does not return an Array. try changing to `[instant_message]` instead of `instant_message` like the other guy suggested

Comment: So, instead of `return connectors.IM.find({ where: args });`, it should be `return [connectors.IM.find({ where: args })];`?

Comment: Updated my answer with the `instant_message` list in the Query type, tell me what you think

Comment: I just tried that but the anomaly is still present. Could you post a quick bit of sample code?

Comment: Did you try it without the `[]` surrounding the `find`?

Comment: Just to clarify VikR's comment: All the Apollo libraries use standard GraphQL, there's no different syntax for it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the query does not expect an array,
Please fix it:

`type Query {
  instant_message(fromID: String, toID: String, msgText: String): [instant_message]
}`

Then you should make sure the resolver returns Array of objects, if it doesnt work then the resolver is not returning an Array.

Comment: I have updated the schema to `type Query {
  instant_message(fromID: String, toID: String, msgText: String): [instant_message]
}`, and the resolver is `return connectors.IM.find({ where: args });`. GraphiQL is responding, `"message": "Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field Query.instant_message."`  Do I need to update the resolver as well as the schema?